# How do I navigate from an Android Activity to a Xamarin Forms ContentPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I'm developing an application that uses an online payment. I open the link, for the payment, in a browser using: `Device.OpenUri(Uri);`. When the user has finished paying for his order he gets redirected to an Android Activity using a custom URL scheme:

```
[Activity(Label = "Urlentryclass", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        MainLauncher = false, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] {Android.Content.Intent.ActionView},
        DataScheme = "test",
        Categories = new[] {Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable})]
 public class Urlentryclass : FormsAppCompatActivity
...
```

How do I navigate to a certain Forms content page from this activity? 
I try to open a certain page using the following code example (It's done by using an Event Handler).

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationMenu(sisowStatus, modelStatus)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Followed by `this.finish();`

Hower, the view that's being showed is the last view that was opened before the browser shows.
It seems that `Navigation.PushAsync` doesn't affect the view that's being showed. I've try `PopAsync`, `PopToRootAsync` but nothing seems to be working.

For those that are interested in the Event Handler, here it is:

```
public static class PaymentNavigationHelper
{
    public delegate void PaymentExecutedHandler(string sisowStatus, string orderStatus);
    public static event PaymentExecutedHandler OnPaymentExecuted;

    public static void PaymentExecuted(string sisowStatus, string orderStatus)
    {
        OnPaymentExecuted?.Invoke(sisowStatus, orderStatus);
    }
}
```

I'm subsribing to the event on the Content Page where I'm starting the payment:

```
 PaymentNavigationHelper.OnPaymentExecuted += (sisowStatus, modelStatus) =>
 {
     Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationMenu(sisowStatus, modelStatus)).ConfigureAwait(false);
 };
```

In the activity which handles the payment url, the following code is being used:

```
PaymentNavigationHelper.PaymentExecuted(status, test.Model.FirstOrDefault().Status);
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered on following link:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/182108#Comment_182108